# Ionic 3 formControl ion-select initial value

Tags: angular, forms, ionic-framework, angular2-formbuilder

I am working on an Ionic application and want to implement a simple form page. I want to reuse the same component for both creating and editing the entity that I am working with.

One of the fields that I need my users to input is "occasion" which in my model is an object that contains id, name and some other fields.

It works great for adding, but when I go to this page with an entity in place already, in order to edit it, all the fields are pre-filled, but the ion-select.

This is a part of the code in component constructor:

```
this.editedWish = navParams.get('wish') || null;
if (this.editedWish) {
  this.isEdited = true;
  this.title = this.editedWish.title;
  this.description = this.editedWish.description;
  this.occasion = this.editedWish.occasion;
}

this.form = formBuilder.group({
  title: [this.title, Validators.required],
  description: [this.description],
  occasion: [this.occasion, Validators.required]
});
```

As far as the html template is concerned:

```
 <ion-item>
    <ion-select formControlName="occasion" interface="popover">
      <ion-option *ngFor="let occasion of occasions" [value]="occasion">
        {{occasion.name | translate }}
      </ion-option>
    </ion-select>
  </ion-item>
```

Do you guys know why the ion-select does not get pre-filled as well?
Thanks for helping

Comment: Can you replicate your code on stackblitz or plunkr?

Comment: Ion-select requires ngmodel to show initial/default value.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem few time ago, and this works for me (add the 'translate' attribute):

```
<ion-option *ngFor="let occasion of occasions" [value]="occasion" translate="occasion.name">       
  </ion-option>
```